# Storing execution parameters in the Airflow database

Tags: airflow

I am creating DAGs having parameters changing (possibly) every run.

Is there a way to store them in the Airflow metadata db? This would allow having a single db containing full run audit (list of runs with their parameters, statuses, etc).

Currently I use XComs pushing them within the execute method of operators but (except for the fact that's not what XComs are for) it's not easy to query them (as they are serialized by SqlAlchemy to blobs).

Answer (score 1):

You can store them as [Airflow Variables](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#variables) - it won't store execution date by default like XComs, but you should be able to add that manually.

Comment: I don't think I'd be able to see what variable value was used in each execution, would I?

Comment: Are you looking to view it in a tasks log? or in the Task Instance Details?

Comment: I'd like to be able to query it in the underlying metadata database.

Comment: You shouldn't have any issue with that with Variables - they get their own table. You can also see what was use in the "Task Instance Details" view